# How to get an element attribute from an array adapter

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development, and I'm getting hung up on something that's probably pretty basic, but I'm having difficulty finding an answer.

i'm trying to start a new activity and pass in the name attribute of the selected item from a list view.  I want to use the name attribute because then i can use that value to reference a different strings xml file and create a new listview in the second activity.

Here is my main_activity_layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

</ListView>
```

Here is my xml file that is used to create the list view on the main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
  <string-array name="guidelines">
    <item name = "abc">Option 1</item>
    <item name = "def">Option 2</item>

  </string-array>
</resources>
```

Here is my Java code:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {


ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
String[] hello;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.guidelines)));

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

}



}
```

I want to pass the name attribute from the selected list item in the mainActivity to the second activity in order to create a list view from a different xml file with the same name as the selected option.

Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` attribute from your `string-array` resource is ignored by android. If you want to use something akin to that, use a `HashMap` to map the `<item>` contents to the activity names.